# Session variable not saving on hosting but in localhost in php

Tags: php, session-variables

I am trying to add multi language in a web but im having problems with a session variable.

i have this:

```
session_start();
$lang = $_SESSION['lang'];
echo $_SESSION['lang'];
$languages = array('es', 'en');
if(in_array($_GET['lang'], $languages)){
$_SESSION['lang']=$_GET['lang'];
$lang = $_SESSION['lang'];
echo $lang;
}
include("translations/lang.php");
```

Links to change the language:

```
<li><a href="?lang=es">Español</a></li>
<li><a href="?lang=en">Ingles</a></li>
```

When i click on one of the links the $lang variable stores the $_SESSION['lang'] that is = to $_GET['lang'] it works on localhost (Wamp) but when i put it on the hosting it doesnt work when change to other page inside the web the $_SESSION['lang'] disappears.

Can you help me please.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It might be a permissions thing. I haven't played with php or php sessions for a while, but my memory says that the default implementation is to store session data in some system directory.

Answer (score 0):

> it doesnt work when change to other page inside the web the
>   $_SESSION['lang'] disappears

Are you sure you are using:

```
session_start();
```

in all your pages?

Comment: yes, session_start() is in the header.php file that is called from the rest of the web.

Answer (score 0):

I've come across a similar situation before and I was able to fix it by changing the PHP version from my hosting service panel (CPanel).

In my case, the default PHP version was set to 7.4(native). After changing the PHP version to 7.2 I was able to save the session variable. I also tried changing the PHP version to 7.4 (without the parenthesised "native", as my hosting service offered two variants of PHP 7.4) and the problem did not return.

It is possible that the default PHP version permissions caused the issue.